# Joomla 3.0 Breadcrumbs to show parent page

Tags: joomla, breadcrumbs

I need my breadcrumb trail to show the parent page but instead it shows all the pages from the category.

I have tried a couple of different modules but all do the same.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add an example/screenshot and clarify what you expected to happen and how the output is different from the desired one?

Comment: yes, here there is a screenshot http://img90.imageshack.us/img90/4845/zr04.jpg If from Faculty I click in Network, the page will display all the pages with the category Network and not the page with alias Network.

Comment: So you have got a name conflict. It will be really difficult to tell without knowing your configuration. The behavior depends on your SEF configs and menu entries, among others. I don't think that this question can be answered just based on this short description.

Comment: With SEF turned off, I can see that when i move the mouse over, the url is calling view=category and I want it to display view=article. I've been trying to edit the components/com_content/helpers/route.php but i can't fix the if being parsed. So now I can display an article when clicking on breadcrumbs but it is not the right one.

Comment: First, be very careful before editing core files. Do not do this if you don't know what you are doing. Second, if the breadcrumb is supposed to show a higher level in the hierarchy, namely the category, why should it display an article (or another page) simply because there is another page with that name/alias.